# What's a cheap way to convert a lens into a telescope?

Tags: telephoto

So I've researched this as much as I can online, but so much of the discussion I've found is from 2005 era.

I have a couple of old, nice telephoto lens that I hardly use, and it occurred to me that they'd probably make nice telescopes, and it seems like it must be possible, but it's quite hard to find info on it.

I did find that there's a company that does a lot of macro extension tubes (Kenko I believe?) who do make some converters, but they go for about $180 at B&H, and I'm not interested in paying that much. I thought I could buy a telescope eyepiece for maybe $30 or $50 and somehow attach it to a telephoto lens and make it work somehow?

It seems like an ideal task for a 3D printer, but I don't know how that'd work, especially what exact length I'd need to space between the telescope eyepiece and the lens (if that is indeed how I'd do it).

Anyone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using photographic lenses to do something other than take photographs.

Comment: perhaps http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate place for this question?

Comment: @MichaelClark I do not agree. What if the user wanted to photograph stars?

Comment: Then you would connect the lens to the camera, not ask how to make a DIY adapter so you can use the lens without a camera. We already have quite a number of the first type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not hold a lens in one hand and the objective in the other, look through that and see what distance works? I did that with a loupe and a macro filter, and was able to see the image and easily get tye distance.